# mupdf utility pdfdraw output quality always the same whatever dpi and antialiasing parameter I feed it with

Tags: windows, pdf, rendering, utility

I am using mupdf utility pdfdraw under Windows but I see that the output is the same for example between 60 and 96 dpi and whatever antialiasing bit parameter I put on the command-line. Processing time is different instead. What's wrong?

Comment: OK, the dpi parameter also affects width and height, so it appears the same when zooming in, except for very high dpi when it appears very well.